# How to optimize a query that compares data from the same day for each month

Tags: oracle, oracle12c

I have a query that gets data from a given day and compares it with the same business day for each month (if it turns to be Sat, Sun, or holiday it should show the last day before i.e. if I say 25, it will return Sep 23, 2022, for September and Aug 25 for August, etc). DAILY_DATA table contains business days only, so this works:

```
SELECT *
FROM DAILY_DATA A, --It has partitions for every day, like 'PART_300922'
(   SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE,'MM'),MAX(DATE) DATE
    FROM DAILY_DATA
    WHERE TO_CHAR(DATE,'YYYY')='2022'
    AND TO_CHAR(DATE,'DD')<=TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(&query_date),'DD')
    GROUP BY TO_CHAR(DATE,'MM')
    )B
WHERE A.DATE = B.DATE
ORDER BY 1;
```

The problem is, it takes so long time cause it loops thorough the entire table, is there a way to optimize it? maybe using partitions or something?
Help please.

Comment: You can't optimize anything that uses a sub-query in the SELECT statement, because that sub-query has to execute for every single row of the table. In addition, the repeated function calls to `TO_CHAR` slow execution as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH prep_daily_data(dat, dim, mdat) AS (
    SELECT 
        d.dat, 
        TO_CHAR( d.dat , 'DD'),
        TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(d.dat,'YYYYMM')) as mdat
    FROM daily_data d
),
matching_dim(dat, next_dat) AS (
    SELECT cm.dat, nm.dat
    FROM prep_daily_data cm
    JOIN prep_daily_data nm ON cm.dim = nm.dim AND cm.mdat+1 = nm.mdat
),
matching_others(dat, next_dat) AS (
    SELECT dat, MAX(next_dat) FROM (
        SELECT cm.dat AS dat, nm.dat AS next_dat
        FROM prep_daily_data cm
        JOIN prep_daily_data nm ON cm.dim > nm.dim AND cm.mdat+1 = nm.mdat
        WHERE NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM matching_dim d WHERE d.dat = cm.dat)
    ) 
    GROUP BY dat
)
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM matching_dim
    UNION ALL
    SELECT * FROM matching_others
)
ORDER BY dat
;
```